# How to deal with very large databases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, performance

I've got a `DataTable` which can have hundreds of thousands of records placed in it. This is a huge memory overhead, so I have added a feature whereby users can only visualise the top 200 records in my application, and can export the rest of the results to a CSV file.

However, in order to export to a CSV file, the method which I am using, does so by converting the contents of a `DataTable` to a CSV file. Since I can have over 100K records in the DataTable, I think it would be too much of a memory hog to place all records into the DataTable and map to the CSV file. What approach would be recommended? This is my CSV mapping code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dtResults.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
            builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

            foreach (DataRow row in dtResults.Rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => DisplayCommas(field.ToString()));
                builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            }

            File.WriteAllText(filename, builder.ToString());
```

Comment: hundreds of thousands of records is "moderate"; not "very large". That is about the point when you start realizing you need to do things like "sorting and paging at the server", rather than fetching everything into a `DataTable`.  What is the database you are using here? Are you using "database" and "CSV" as synonyms here?

Comment: @MarcGravell - Users can apply my application to any database of their choice, so it can theoretically be as big as the biggest database available (although these cases would be very few). Users can use my application to query their databases, and view the results of their query as a DataGrid which is produced from a DataTable. I would however like to export the contents of the DataTable to a CSV file, however am worrying that there might be instances where the DataTable would consume too much memory

Comment: indeed; and for that reason, `DataTable` is very rarely used outside of small applications...

Comment: What if you executed an IDataReader against the database to do the outputting? Shouldn't create the huge memory overhead.

Comment: I would like to raise the important fact that you are displaying this theoretically large result set in a control. You are going to need to use record virtualization and streaming results to the grid if you want to allow for this type of ui access. If you think building up a CSV string consumes a lot of in memory, wait until you see the consumption for rendering a grid control populated from that same data.

Comment: @JakeHeidt - I only plan on showing the top 200 results in the DataGrid, while all the other results can be viewed when exporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, working with the heavyweight DataTable here is to be avoided given your requirements. So streaming data from the source using its provider's data reader is going to give you the best performance while maintaining a slim memory profile.

I did some quick searches, but couldn't come up with any csv library implementations (there are a ton, far from an exhaustive search) that touted easy plug-n-play with a DataReader. However it would be fairly trivial to use a CSV library (i have used FileHelpers and kbcsv with success before) to handle the file writing, load up the data reader from your query, tell the csv writer the column names before you start looping and then just let the writer handle streaming the results to disk.

You might get some memory increase during this, since the file write stream will probably have a decent buffer, but it will be **way** less memory consumption than the datatable-centric approach. The only drawback I can really see from using a datareader with a large result set in this fashion is the drain that a long running query can potentially have from a ADO.NET data provider, but thats completely provider specific (but a common problem) which you can look into if you have issues on the database side once you go down this route.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go old school and use sqlcmd. Something like:

```
sqlcmd -q "select field1,field2,field3 from mytable" -oc:\output.csv -h-1 -s","
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Can this be used within C# though? Furthermore, I'd also like to export results to XML and Excel - would this solution be modifiable to support those formats, or is it strictly CSV only?

Comment: You neglected to mention XML or Excel above. For XML I'd use the SELECT FOR XML clause (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx). Excel can open .csv files

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the DataTable and use a DataReader. Sequentially read the records you need and build the CSV file as you go.